# Allow the execution of an external PHP script for logged users

Tags: php, wp-blog-header.php

I need to call a PHP script external to WP and I would like to take advantage of the credentials of WP so that only logged users can access this script. I have tried to use this code embedded in my external PHP script but it would not work (where XXX is the domain name):

```
    require('/var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx.xxx/httpdocs/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');

if ( !is_user_logged_in () ) {
   //the script exits if the user is not logged in
   showAccessDenied($day, $month, $year, $area, isset($room) ? $room : "");
   exit;
}
```

Do you have any clue?
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this the other way around:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in () ) {
  //the script exits if the user is not logged in
  require('/path/to/your/script.php');
  showAccessDenied($day, $month, $year, $area, isset($room) ? $room : "");
}
```

You can work that into a page in a number of ways. I don't have enough detail to provide an example that fits your needs.

Comment: Thank you s_ha_dum. I was not clear enough in my question. Indeed, what I need is to test from the external script whether my user is logged in WP. If he is, the user is allowed to do something otherwise he is directed to a denied access page. So I need to perform the test from the external script.

Comment: No one? Must not be so complicated, or?

Comment: I know that what you think you need is to test from the external script... I am not convinced that that is true.

Comment: Let me explain then: I display a planning manager with an external PHP script. I want that only registered users to be able to add an event on the calendar. Of course, the planning is displayed on a WP page that is accessible only to registered users. But, a smart guy could have a direct access to the PHP script. So, to prevent this situation, I want to check that a WP user is trying to edit the planning. Therefore, I think that the only solution is that the PHP script checks whether the user is a registered WP user. Or?...

Comment: OR? -- Or have your script check for a WordPress global like `ABSPATH` and die if it isn't defined. Or have your script accept requests only from your IP. Or parse requests only if a particular hash is included. Or have your script not parse HTTP requests at all. Or some combination of the above, probably. You seen to be thinking of only a very subset of approaches.

Comment: You are mentioning many possibilities that I don't know. I'm a newbie in coding (rather code-modifier than code-creator). I confess easily that I don't know how to introduce any of your additional solutions. If you are kind enough to guide me, of course I can try other tricks if you think that one or the combination of several of the solutions listed by you is better/easier than the one I was thinking of initially...

Comment: Does `script.php` contain anything but function definitions?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure to understand your question. You mean the php script (planning manager)? In this case, no, it does not contain only function definitions (I can upload the file here if there is a way to do so). The part of the script that I intend to amend is:
    if (!getAuthorised(1))
    {
    showAccessDenied($day, $month, $year, $area, isset($room) ? $room : "");
    exit;
    }

I must, I believe, change the if (!getAuthorised(1)) into something checking if the user is logged in WP. Thank you for your help!